# Passing whole body as a variable to a POST request

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm trying to create a simple stress test using JMeter. I have mostly GET requests and a couple POST requests. My main goal is to make this test as reusable as possible. I want to implement it in a way that the user would have to provide a CSV file with the following headers:

```
method;path;postBody
```

The values would look something like:

```
GET;/path/to/resource;''
POST;/path/to/resource;'{"key":"value","key":"value","key":"value"}'
```

Now POST (PUT, PATCH etc ..) bodies differ from one request to another. Providing `${postBody}` to Body Data tab does not work `"${postBody}"` as well.

Is there a way to achieve this? Command line solutions are more than welcome as well.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm using the UI interface. When I input `${postBody}` in the Body Data tab the UI complains. When switching from the Body Data tab to another one I get the following prompt:

[image: Error prompt]

Comment: What doesn't work?maybe you need also headers from CSV

Comment: not clear what exactly doesn't work. For POST, sending `${postBody}` as a body should work, provided it's properly url-encoded. GET normally expects parameters with URL (so should be on path). But since we don't know what doesn't work, there can be 100s of other reasons too

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "'" around the request and it should work.

Regarding the warning you get, it is not an error, it is just that in JMeter those 2 tabs are exclusive:

- Parameters tabs is for input of parameters in the form as name=value
- Body data is for your kind of requirement

So can you test my hypothesis which is to remove the quote around the request in CSV file ?

If it still fails, please show the logs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17725739)

Comment: The first part is the answer. Where do you see a critique ? thx

Comment: Yes thank you! I got so hanged on the warning thinking it's an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can remain in Body Data tab,

Add after pathPost your optional query parameters for GET request:

```
 ${pathPost}?${getPramaters}
```

Don't worry about the `?` it's just seperate path from parameters

Also consider changing variable name to path, more suitable because it can be POST.

In JSON `,` seperate between values while in CSV default is also `,`

I suggest you can your CSV delimiter, In `CSV Data Set Config` Choose different Delimiter as `;` and add your data in CSV accordingly (remove extra ' characters):

```
POST;/path/to/resource;{"key":"value","key":"value","key":"value"}
```

- Notice: Allow quoted data keep default value `False`

Comment: You're right `pathPost` should be `path`. But the issue is in the body of the post request where I cannot provide the body data as a variable retrieved from the CSV.